# Identifying unique indices in columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this practice dataset

```
table = {'name': ['Harris',
                  'Jericho','Keenan','Korbyn','Wes','Eliezer',
                  'Jeffery','Kalel','Kylian','Turner','Willie','Rogelio','Ephraim'],
        'math': random.sample(range(0, 100), 13),
        'english':random.sample(range(0, 100), 13),
        'science':random.sample(range(0, 100), 13),
        'geo':random.sample(range(0, 100), 13),
        'chemistry':random.sample(range(0, 100), 13),
        'physics':random.sample(range(0, 100), 13)}

x = pd.DataFrame(table)
x.set_index('name')
```

I would like to identify for each subject, the top 3 students in the class, that aren't the top students in the other subjects.

For example, if Harris and Jericho are the top students in math, but they are also the top students in another subject, they won't be chosen.

I know how to get the top students per subject but I don't know how to get top students in 1 subject only.

Comment: maybe get top 3 students from all subjects and later count them using `collections.Count` - or if you will have all results in one list then you can use `my_list.count("Harris")` - and then you check all students and get names which gives 1.

Comment: if you use pandas then first sort by `math` and get top 3 persons, next sort by `english` and get top 3 persons, etc. And later count how many times names are in results and get names which gives 1

Comment: if you want use `name` as index then you have to assing result `x = x.set_index('name')` OR you have to do it `in place` like `x.set_index('name', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand all.

---

You can sort by column `math` and get top 3 rows and get indexes to get top 3 students for `math`.

```
x.sort_values('math', ascending=False)[:3].index
```

You can repeate it for all columns and keep names on list

```
results = []

for column_name in x.columns:
    names = x.sort_values(column_name, ascending=False)[:3].index.tolist()
    results += names
    print(column_name, ':', names)
```

Now you can use standard `.count(studen_name)` to get how many times he/she was in top.

```
for name in x.index:
    print(name, results.count(name))
```

You need persons which gives value `1` so you can use `if`

```
for name in x.index:
    count = results.count(name)
    if count == 1:
        print(name, ':', count)
```

This gives persons which were in top only in one subject.

If you need person which was in top for `math` then you can check these persons with

```
x.sort_values('math', ascending=False)[:3].index
```

---

```
import random
import pandas as pd

random.seed(0)  #  to have always the same random values

table = {'name': ['Harris',
                  'Jericho','Keenan','Korbyn','Wes','Eliezer',
                  'Jeffery','Kalel','Kylian','Turner','Willie','Rogelio','Ephraim'],
        'math': random.sample(range(0, 100), 13),
        'english':random.sample(range(0, 100), 13),
        'science':random.sample(range(0, 100), 13),
        'geo':random.sample(range(0, 100), 13),
        'chemistry':random.sample(range(0, 100), 13),
        'physics':random.sample(range(0, 100), 13)}

x = pd.DataFrame(table)
x.set_index('name', inplace=True)
print(x)

results = []

for column_name in x.columns:
    names = x.sort_values(column_name, ascending=False)[:3].index.tolist()
    results += names
    print(column_name, ':', names)

print(results)

for name in x.index:
    count = results.count(name)
    if count == 1:
        print(name, results.count(name))
        print('math:', name in x.sort_values('math', ascending=False)[:3].index.tolist())
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond to my question. My town lost power but once its back, I'll try this solution out.